# Finding general expression for the following sequence:

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find a general expression for the following sequence:

1, 14, 273, 7645, 296296, ...

I've already looked at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS) and this is a known sequence, related to the Central Factorial Numbers. But they don't give a general formula for it, only a recursive one. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please link to said OEIS in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In our [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C%2014%2C%20273%2C%207645%2C%20296296&sort=&language=english&go=Search), there is a clearly stated formula that goes as follows:

$$a(n)=s(n+3,3)^2-2s(n+3,2)s(n+3,4)+2s(n+3,1)s(n+3,5)$$

where $s(n,k)$ are the [stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind).

Comment: Not that I want to split hairs, but these numbers themselves might not really have a closed form.

Comment: @ClementC. Sh... your not supposed to say that...

Comment: @ClementC. Well, there is this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Other_relations

Answer (score 0):

At any case, the problem is not well defined. According to the Lagrange's Interpolation Formula, we can construct infinite sequences $a_n=p(n)$ with $p$ a polynomial and $a_1,\ldots,a_5$ the given numbers.